# Undefined Columns Selected using General Social Survey in R

Tags: r, indexing, subset

I am trying to analyze General Social Survey using R code and am using script I found online at this url:

https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/blob/master/General%20Social%20Survey/cumulative%20cross-sectional%20-%20analysis%20examples.R

However, I keep getting this message and can't find a solution:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(frame, , j, drop = drop) :    undefined
>   columns selected

Here is the code I am using slightly adapted from the link above:

```
options(digits = 8)
library(foreign) 
library(survey)  
library(memisc)
options( survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")

GSS.CS.file.location <- "http://gss.norc.org/documents/spss/GSS_spss.zip"

tf <- tempfile() ; td <- tempdir()
download.file(GSS.CS.file.location, tf, mode = "wb")
fn <- unzip(tf, exdir = td, overwrite = T)
print( fn[grep("sav$", fn)] )

dat.pov<-as.data.set(spss.system.file(fn[grep("sav$", fn)]))
z <- dat.pov
rm(dat.pov)
gc()
dat.pov <- z
rm(z)
gc()

save(dat.pov, file = "dat.pov.rda")
load("dat.pov.rda")
nrow(dat.pov)
ncol(dat.pov)
head(dat.pov)
```

## narrow down dataframe to desired variables

```
KeepVars<- c("oversamp", "formwt", "wtssall", "sampcode", "sample", "sex", 
             "age","region","nateduc","nateducy", "nateducz", "natefare", 
             "natefarey","natefarez","race","res16","income","partyid",
             "polviews","educ","degree", "eqwlth","helpful","fair","trust",
             "jobfind","class","rank","satfin", "finalter","finrela","unemp",
             "getahead","parsol","kidssol","helppoor")

dat.pov2 <- dat.pov[,KeepVars]
```

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: So now that I have that large dataset downloaded, saved as .rda, and in memory, are there any interesting research questions I can ask?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you check to see whether all those KeepVars are "in" the column names, you should see where your errors are:

```
> KeepVars %in% names(dat.pov)
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[14] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[27]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

You can even invert the logical vector to select the names that are not `%in%` the names.

```
> KeepVars[ ! KeepVars %in% names(dat.pov)]
[1] "natefare"  "natefarey" "natefarez"
```

Note... I did not do the double assignment and gc() operations that Anthony needed to do on his severely memory-constrained laptop. (It made no sense to do that on a machine with 32 G, but I do strongly doubt that could make a difference in this instance.)

This returns the names that have "nate" in them:

```
> names(dat.pov)[ grepl("nate", names(dat.pov))]
[1] "natenvir" "nateduc"  "natenrgy" "natenviy" "nateducy" "natenviz" "nateducz"
```

And this lists the names that have "fare" in them:

```
> names(dat.pov)[ grepl("fare", names(dat.pov))]
 [1] "natfare"  "natfarey" "natfarez" "farewhts" "farejews" "fareblks" "fareasns"
 [8] "farehsps" "fareso"   "workfare" "lessfare" "immfare"  "aidsfare" "welfare1"
[15] "welfare2" "welfare3" "welfare4" "welfare5" "welfare6"
```

That last character vector seems to be where you will find the names you misspelled.